# returning all records with the same ID but different values

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I've been trying this query

```php
Model::find()
 ->innerJoin('TranslationTable', 'TranslationTable.model_id = Model.id')
 ->where(['IN', 'translation_code', $arrayOfTranslationCodes])
 ->asArray()
 ->all();
```

The translation table contains multiple rows with the same ID but with different translation codes.

This query only returns the first matching locale for a given ID. How would I retrieve the other translation codes for a given ID?

Comment: What does `$arrayOfTranslationCodes` contain?

Comment: @RonInbar an array of translation codes; codes that are inside the translation_code column in the translationTable.

Comment: @ParmjitGill Have you verified that `$arrayOfTranslationCodes` contain more then `one` code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the solution that I came to:

```php
$query = Model::find()
            -> innerJoin('TranslationTable', 'TranslationTable.model_id = Model.id');

foreach ($arrayOfTranslationCodes as $translation)
{
   $query->andWhere(['OR', 'translation_code', $translation])
}

$queryResponse = $query->asArray()->all();
```

This allowed me to find rows with the same id, but have different translations. You need to store the `$query->asArray()->all();` as `$query` itself just returns the active query.